# What's wrong with the constraint on this SQL table create?

Tags: sql, h2, unique-constraint, create-table

I am trying to create a new crosswalk/junction table (`synonyms`) that:

1. Consists of a pair of IDs (both a foreign key to a different table); and
2. Has a uniqueness constraint such that both IDs (as a pair) must be unique on the table

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE synonyms (
    base_word_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    synonym_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_words_based_id FOREIGN KEY (base_word_id) REFERENCES words(word_id)
);
```

The `words` table contains (you guessed it), words and metadata about those words. The `synonyms` table is a many-to-many table holding the relationship of words and their synonyms, which are other words. The `synonym_id` is the ID of the word that is a synonym of the word represented by the `base_word_id`.

Against an H2 DB I get the following error:

```
Error: Table "WORDS" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE synonyms(
base_word_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
synonym_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT fk_words_based_id FOREIGN KEY (base_word_id) REFERENCES words(word_id)
) [42102-173]
SQLState:  42S02
ErrorCode: 42102
```

In my DB, `WORDS` is not a table, but `words` is. So it looks like H2 is upper-casing `words` to `WORDS` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created the table "words" like this:

```
create table "words"(...)
```

If you do that, then the table name is case sensitive, and you will have to always quote it. To avoid that, create the table without double quotes:

```
create table words(...)
```